# Bat replace new line char to "|"

Tags: batch-file

I want to replace new line char to "|" use Window bat.

eg file1:

```
1
2
3
```

output:

```
1|2|3
```

I try this bat:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (123.txt) do (
set a=%%a
set a=!a:"\r\n"=^|!
for  %%b in ("!a!") do (
echo.%%~b>>1245.txt
))
pause
```

But, new line char is not "\r\n". How can I get the new line char expression ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Initialize the output line
set "line="

rem Catenate all file lines in the same variable separated by "|"
for /F "delims=" %%a in (123.txt) do set "line=!line!|%%a"

rem Show final line, removing the leading "|"
echo !line:~1!>>1245.txt
```

Comment: Why Catenate operation do not work in cmd or bat file?

Comment: I don't understand you. What do you mean with "Catenate operation"? There is not any command that perform a "Catenate operation" in Batch files...

Comment: I named that part of your code which you commented as "Catenate all file lines". I tried to do your code myself, but SET will not allow me to change a variable declared before the loop.

Comment: The above code works as it is. If you _modify it_, then I have not any way to know what the problem is if I don't see the modified code... Hint: are you using delayed expansion: `!line!` and _not_ standard expansion: `%line%` ?

Comment: Yes, I did that. However, I found my mistake. I wanted to output the intermediate result of the "Catenate" immediately in a loop. That is, I entered the ECHO command into the body of the loop. And I wanted to see the text being put together step by step. When I returned the ECHO outside the cycle, the "Catenate" occurred. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with this a little bit:

```
FOR /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%@ IN ("File.txt") DO (
<NUL Set /P "=%%@"
)
```

or this, the /p removes the newLines:

```
C:\> echo Hello World
Hello World

C:\> echo|set /p=Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: I want newLines replace to "|" ...

    echo off
    FOR /F "Usebackq Tokens=*" %%@ IN ("File.txt") DO (
    <NUL Set /P "=%%@|"
    )

Comment: But will output two "|" in tail.

Comment: maybe because of \r and \n. 
Are you sure that you have one line end btw? :D

Answer (score 0):

with a some edits of Krekkon's script:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "Usebackq Tokens=* delims=" %%# IN ("123.txt") DO (
  echo|set /p=%%#^^^|
)>>temp.file
move /y "temp.file" "123.txt"
```